# Perl cgi string to float number

Tags: perl, cgi

This is what I have in my html file

```
<form action="drinks.cgi" method="POST" target="re">
...
Quantity:<input name="Quan" type="number" step="any"> (ml)
<input style="margin-left:20px" type="submit" value="submit"/>
...
...
</form>
```

and this is what in the cgi file

```
my $quan = $conn->quote($cgi->param(Quan));
printf $quan;
```

let's say I type `222` in the input

I expected it printed out `222` only but it printed out `'222'` instead...
how can I get rid of the two ' in my cgi file so that I can use the variable for other calculations.

Comment: Incomplete question. You don't say what $conn is, are we supposd to guess? Likely a DBI instance and you're quoting a value then wondering why you get quotes when you print it?

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche Sorry... it's SQL

Comment: There's no such class on CPAN, so saying that is completely useless.

Comment: Tip: `printf $quan;` is wrong. It should be `print $quan;` or `printf "%s", $quan;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the calculations are to be done in Perl, use

```
my $quan = $cgi->param('Quan');
```

If the calculations are to be done in SQL, start with the above and follow up with

```
die if $quan !~ /^[0-9]+\z/;
my $quan_sqllit = $quan;
```

or

```
# The quotes aren't actually a problem.
my $quan_sqllit = $conn->quote($quan);
```

or

```
my $quan_sqllit = "CAST(".$conn->quote($quan)." AS INT)";
```

or

```
# Maybe. Depends on the implementation of $conn->quote.
my $quan_sqllit = $conn->quote(0+$quan);
```